# ASP.net-Core: How to use different [display name] value for each instance?

Tags: asp.net-core, displayattribute

I have two classes that similar in every thing but member display names are different.
My solution was creating two classes, but this is not compliant with coding standards.
Is there another way to solve that?
I expect that supporting multiple [Display name] values, or separate [Display name] for each instance maybe help me.

Comment: Can you provide some code or example to describe the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding your problem, you can create a superclass, collect the common features in this class, and then inherit the other classes.